# Python using mechanize to login from a text file

Tags: python, authentication, mechanize

Edit: Yes this is my own website.

I'm using a a text file which has over 2000+ passwords in it, one of which is the right password placed by me, this Is then used to iterate through the passwords and check if it's the right password using mechanize.

But the problem Is It never recognises It but It does recognise If I set the password to the correct password? No idea why this happens so I'm posting this thread.

Here is the code:

```
import mechanize

f = open("words.txt", 'r')                                                # 
opens the word list you specified
for line in f: 

    br = mechanize.Browser() 

    br.open("http://185.40.21.34/pages/examples/login.php")
    br.select_form("form")
    print "Current password:", line

    br["email"] = "Test"
    br["password"] = line
    br.submit()
    if br.geturl() == "http://185.40.21.34/index.php":                      
        print "Password found !"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you iterate through a file all the lines are gonna end by \n
To correct that you have to write

```
line = line.replace('\n', '')
```

Comment: I did see this \n come up but i thought it was ok because when i print line it was the just the word. I'll give it a go :)

Comment: Didn't seem to work?

passw = line.replace('\n', 'y')
br["password"] = passw

Comment: Just realised you added 'y' needed to remove that :)

Comment: Oh oops didn't see that